# sed - replace all strings that begin with

Tags: replace, sed

Hi I want to find all strings anywhere in a file that begin with the letters `rs` i.e.

```
rs12345 100
rs54321 200
300 rs13579
```

and delete all strings that begin with the criteria so that I get:

```
100
200
300
```

i.e. replace the string with nothing. I am not bothered about leading whitespace before final output as I deal with that later. I have tried `sed 's/rs*//g'` however this gives:

```
12345 100
54321 200
```

i.e. only removes the `rs`.

How do I edit my sed command to delete the entire string? Thanks

Comment: Only at the beginning of a line or anywhere in the file?

Comment: @brucezepplin oh, I thought it was just at the beginning of the file. Just updated also doing it like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace from starting `rs` up to a space by an empty string, so that the `rsXXX` gets removed.

```
sed 's/^rs[^ ]*//' file
```

This supposed your `rs` was in the beginning of the line. If `rs` can appear anywhere in the file, use:

```
sed 's/\brs[^ ]*//' file
```

The `\b` works as word boundary, so that things like `hellorshello` does not match.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
rs12345 100
rs54321 200
hellooo 300
$ sed 's/^rs[^ ]*//' a
 100
 200
hellooo 300
```

Note I am not dealing with the whitespace, since you mention you are handling it later on. In case you needed it, you can say `sed 's/^rs[^ ]* \+//' file`.

`rs` anywhere:

```
$ cat a
rs12345 100
rs54321 200
hellooo 300
and rs12345 100
thisrsisatest 24
$ sed 's/\brs[^ ]*//' a
 100
 200
hellooo 300
and  100
thisrsisatest 24
```

---

Note you current approach wasn't working because with `rs*` you are saying: `r` followed by 0 or more `s`.

Comment: this appears to work whe the line begins with the string of interest, however if the string occurs in column 2, this does not appear to work. I will edit my question to reflect this

Comment: Yep, I just saw your comment in the question and updated my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Let the *word* be a pattern starting with word break `\b` and having characters `\w` (and ending with `\b` too, but we will not need it).

The command that removes words starting with *rs* will be `sed -r 's/\brs\w+//g' file`

```
$ cat file
rs12345 100
rs54321 200
ars1234 000
$ sed -r 's/\brs\w+//g' file
 100
 200
ars1234 000
```