# sed program to replace strings starting with a specific character

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I know similar questions have been asked around, like for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939241/sed-replace-all-strings-that-begin-with), but I've been unable to reproduce desired results for my own needs with such examples, and I don't understand why.

I want to replace all words in a file starting with the character '@' by <@MENTION>. For example, this:

> I have 6 @emailaddresses and 10% of the people don't eat sandwiches!
> I have six @emailaddresses and 10%...  @123_Username @BAPP,
> you shouldn't say that! I recently called@User but he didn't answer.
> @Username is not a nice person! This @username guy is really cool!

Should become this:

> I have 6 <@MENTION> and 10% of the people don't eat sandwiches! I have
> six <@MENTION> and 10%...  <@MENTION> <@MENTION>, you shouldn't
> say that! I recently called@User but he didn't answer. <@MENTION> is
> not a nice person! This <@MENTION> guy is really cool!

I have tried this:

`sed 's/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/<@MENTION>/'`

But the string '@BAPP' is not taken into account, which I'd like to, and 'called@User' is taken into account, which I would prefer to avoid.

I also tried this:

`sed -E -e 's/\b@[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\b/<@MENTION>/'`

But for a reason I don't know the word boundaries are not taken into account...

Any help to help me understand my way around this would be much appreciated, as I'm (obviously) learning and have a limited experience with Bash. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It would appear that answering a dupe is quicker than finding the matching dupe ;D

Comment: Do you mean that my question is a duplicate? I'm sorry if that is the case, but not being a programmer, I sometimes do not understand some explanations given and thus go by a helpful answer without knowing it... : /

Comment: It certainly is ... just because they're looking for a different starting character than you doesn't make the problem a different one.

Comment: I just noticed the thread in question, sorry then, but I didn't realize that the '@' character would prevent me from using '\b' the way I was trying to, as explained below by someone else, so even though this was a dupe, and that was probably annoying for you guys, it helped me better understand how to use `sed`, so thanks for your patience everyone! : )

Comment: We live an learn ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `sed` idea:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^|[^[:alnum:]])@[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/\1<@MENTION>/g' file
```

**NOTE:** the initial `^` was added to address the case where the desired string is at the beginning of the line.

This generates:

```
# assuming embedded linefeeds

I have 6 <@MENTION> and 10% of the people don't eat sandwiches! I have six
<@MENTION> and 10%... <@MENTION> <@MENTION>, you shouldn't say that! I recently
called@User but he didn't answer. <@MENTION> is not a nice person! This <@MENTION> guy
is really cool!

# assuming no embedded linefeeds

I have 6 <@MENTION> and 10% of the people don't eat sandwiches! I have six <@MENTION> and 10%... <@MENTION> <@MENTION>, you shouldn't say that! I recently called@User but he didn't answer. <@MENTION> is not a nice person! This <@MENTION> guy is really cool!
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! If I may abuse your time and kindness, I have two questions:
1) Why the '\1' before '<@MENTION>'?
2) Why the '[:alnum:]' bit? The way I understand it: "look for strings that start with (^) alphanumeric characters which are then followed by '@' followed by the sequence [a-zA-Z0-9_]*"... Whereas I don't want alphanumeric characters first... I know I'm getting this wrong, but it is confusing to me, as this bit seems unnecessary from my newbie point of view, hence my question...

Comment: @MichaelGauthier  the 1st capture group (`(^|[^[:allnum:]])`) consists of either start of line (`^`) or anything that's *not* in the `[:allnum:]` character class (`[^[:allnum:]]` - here `^` means 'not'); `\1` says to maintain whatever was matched by the 1st capture group; note: in this case there is just the one capture group; everything else matched in the 1st half of the `sed` script (`@[a-zA-Z0-9_]*`) gets replaced with `<@MENTION>`

Comment: Thanks a million times for taking time to explain! I think I get it right now! We want to replace ONLY the '@' bit, so we explicitly mention to the script to keep anything before that bit and not replace it too. Also, the '[:alnum:]' bit here (that was my biggest problem to understand) is used as a way to mainly, if I get it right, detect spaces, and matching patterns/words that would be in the middle of the line. This has the elegance of also matching patterns at the beginning of new sentences where the space was forgotten as well. Thanks a lot again for teaching me! <3

Comment: @MichaelGauthier `[:alnum:]` is a one of several [character class]es(https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html); I'm not sure about other flavors but `GNU` utilities like `sed`, `awk`, `grep` support the use of these character classes

Comment: Yes, I did know about character classes as I looked those up! : )
Thanks a lot again! : )

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is non-standard. It represents a zero-width assertion that a "word" character is on one side and a non-"word" character is on the other. However, the definition of "word" means that it doesn't help you (`@` is not "word" character).

Unless you give the `g` flag to `s///`, it only changes one match per line.

You probably don't want to match `@` not followed by "word" characters, so using `*` is incorrect.

---

Putting that together:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^a-zA-Z_<])@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/\1<@MENTION>/g'
```

- `^|[^a-zA-Z_<]` matches start of line or characters **not** listed in `[]`. Edit to be what you want to exclude. Adding `<` means you don't change existing `<@MENTION>`s.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(\s)@[^ ,.]*/\1<@MENTION>/g' input_file
```

> I have 6 <@MENTION> and 10% of the people don't eat sandwiches! I have six <@MENTION> and 10%... <@MENTION> <@MENTION>, you shouldn't say that! I recently called@User but he didn't answer. <@MENTION> is not a nice person! This <@MENTION> guy is really cool!

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't correctly convert the '@Username' one for me... But thanks for your answer! : )

Comment: @MichaelGauthier Is `@Username` at the start of the new line?

Comment: yes it is, indeed!

Comment: @MichaelGauthier Then you can use `sed -E 's/(^|\s)@[^ ,.]*/\1<@MENTION>/g'`

Answer (score -1):

This sed worked for me:

```
$ sed 's/ @\w*/ <@MENTION>/g' f
I have 6 <@MENTION> and 10% of the people don't eat sandwiches!
I have six <@MENTION> and 10%... <@MENTION> <@MENTION>, you shouldn't say that!
I recently called@User but he didn't answer. <@MENTION> is not a nice person!
This <@MENTION> guy is really cool!
```